# ReactJs - Ant design Tabs Card does not render content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

My components used **ReactJs Framework** that built with **Ant Design UI**. My stucking is the rendering on tabs content.

I try to nest the `LoginForm` component to `TabsCard` component.

*Note*: the LoginForm component can successful independently rendered without nesting case.

Component rendered on image I attachted:

[image]

Here is my code: 
`TabsCard.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'antd';
import LoginForm from '../LoginForm/index.js';

function TabsCard() {
  const tabList = [
    {
      key: 'tab1',
      tab: 'Sign in'
    },
    {
      key: 'tab2',
      tab: 'Sign up'
    }
  ];

  const contentList = {
    tab1: <LoginForm />,
    tab2: <p>signup</p>,
  };

  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('tab1');
  const handleTabChange = key => {
    setActiveTab(key);
  };

  return (
    <Card
      style={{ width: '400' }}
      tabList={tabList}
      activeTabKey={activeTab}
      onTabChange={key => {
        handleTabChange(key);
      }}
    >
      {contentList[setActiveTab]}
    </Card>
  );
}
export default TabsCard;
```

Thank you for your support!

Comment: use `{contentList[activeTab]}` instead of `{contentList[setActiveTab]}`

Comment: @zb22 your code worked to me. maybe I am lacking of the mindset on design a component. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from `contentList[setActiveTab]` to `contentList[activeTab]`

Example of full code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

function TabsCard() {
  const tabList = [
    {
      key: 'tab1',
      tab: 'Sign in'
    },
    {
      key: 'tab2',
      tab: 'Sign up'
    }
  ];

  const contentList = {
    tab1: <div>Login form</div>,
    tab2: <p>signup</p>,
  };

  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('tab1');
  const handleTabChange = key => {
    setActiveTab(key);
  };

  return (
    <Card
      style={{ width: '400' }}
      tabList={tabList}
      activeTabKey={activeTab}
      onTabChange={key => {
        handleTabChange(key);
      }}
    >
      {contentList[activeTab]}
    </Card>
  );
}
export default TabsCard;
```

I hope I've helped you

Have a nice day!

Comment: I was checking the question before the response. So, after dedicate my time and find the error by myself, I decided to add my answer despite someone already answered.